# visual studio code-[Unsupported] in title bar of visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In visual studio code showing [Unsupported] this in the title bar.
And showing "extension host terminated unexpectedly" in notification bar.
if VS Code files have been mistakenly quarantined or removed by anti-virus software.
what will change anti-virus software settings?(quick heal pro).

Comment: What version of VS Code, and which OS and version thereof? When did this start, and was that after an update to VS Code or the OS or the AV? Are you able just to uninstall/reinstall VS Code?

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Install the extension "**Fix VSCode Checksums**"

**2.** Open the command palette **(Ctrl + Shift + P)** and then write and select "**Fix Checksums: Apply**"

**3.** Finally, close VS Code and open it again.